# Jquery click animate randomly stuck after some clicks

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

I have a slider that move from another slider when you click in links.

These Links uses jquery animate function to change the left css paramter. It works, but after some clicks it randomly stuck after some clicks.

The slider starts with a div with 930px width and overflow hidden that works like a mask.

Inside this div has another div (id slide) with a lot of width(200000px) and position:relative, this div comports each slide (divs with width:930px; and float:left the class name is "tratamento")

outside of everything we have the menu... the menu calls jquery click functions that use the functiom animate to change the left position scrolling the content in slide div.

This scripts works...But, after some clicks the clicks randomly dont work for a few seconds. Dont know why, here is the code:

Css:

```
 /* the mask div */
 #corpo2{width:930px;
 margin:80px 25px 20px 25px; 
 overflow:hidden;}

/* this div has every slide inside */
#slide{width:200000px;
position:relative;}

/* class that each slide uses */
.tratamento{
 width:900px;
 padding-right:30px;
 float:left;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="corpo2">
<div id="slide">

<div class="tratamento">
 test 1
</div>

<div class="tratamento">
 test 2
</div>

<div class="tratamento">
 test 3
</div>

</div></div>
```

The menu that calls the click function:

```
    <ul>

    <li><a href="#" class="click1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="click2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="click3">Test 3</a></li>

    </ul>
```

And finnaly the jquery, I load it after everything:

```
    <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".click1" ).click(function(){$('#slide').animate({left: '0px'}, 500 );});
    $( ".click2" ).click(function(){$('#slide').animate({left: '-930px'}, 500 );}); 
    $( ".click3" ).click(function(){$('#slide').animate({left: '-1860px'}, 500 );});    


);

    </script>
```

I tried everything, I removed (document).ready, used and removed type="text/javascript" in the script tag and tried the bind function. It still ramdonly stops to work.

```
$( ".click1" ).bind("click", function(){$('#slide').animate({left: '0px'}, 500 );});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".click1" ).click(function(){$('#slide').stop().animate({left: '0px'}, 500 );});
    $( ".click2" ).click(function(){$('#slide').stop().animate({left: '-930px'}, 500 );}); 
    $( ".click3" ).click(function(){$('#slide').stop().animate({left: '-1860px'}, 500 );}); 
);
```